# GWT.getModuleBaseURL() returns an incorrect value

Tags: gwt

I am running a GWT application in development mode out of Glassfish 3.1.1 (launched with a -noserver argument).

When I call `GWT.getModuleBaseURL()`, the following URL is returned: `http://localhost:8080/appName/appName/`

The correct URL should be `http://localhost:8080/appName/`. I wonder what I did wrong, so that the application name is appended twice.

By the way, `GWT.getHostPageBaseURL();` returns the correct URL.

Comment: Maybe this has something to do that both module name in GWT and context root in Glassfish are set to "appName"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comment is spot on - that is what getModuleBaseURL() does, it returns the path to inside the compiled module, where the generated JavaScript and images are stored. If you launch the app from the url `http://localhost:8080/appName`, that is the host page, but if you look in firebug or another inspector, you probably see a request for `http://localhost:8080/appName/appName/appName.nocache.js` which is the bootstrap JS file. It is the directory where that is contained that the module base url refers to.