# GWT Servlet not getting called from GWT Form Panel integrated in web application

Tags: java, servlets, gwt

I have one GWT application which has one form panel with file upload in it. Then there is one servlet which is there to process uploaded file. This entire application is integrated within one struts web application.

Following are the code snippet:

```
final FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
form.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"upload");
form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
VerticalPanel formPanel = new VerticalPanel();
form.setWidget(formPanel);

Label lblSelectFile = new Label();
lblSelectFile.setText("Select cient_secret.json file: ");
formPanel.add(lblSelectFile);

FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
fileUpload.setName("fileUpload");
formPanel.add(fileUpload);

Button upload = new Button("Upload");
upload.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });

formPanel.add(upload);

form.addSubmitHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitHandler() {
    public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event) {
          if (fileUpload.getName().length() == 0) {
                    Window.alert("The file must not be empty");
                        event.cancel();
          }
      }
    });

form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {
 public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
           Window.alert(event.getResults());
 }
```

});

web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
      com.test.FileUploadServlet
  </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*/upload</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now the problem is this servlet is not getting called from form panel and i'm getting HTTP Status 404.

What wrong am I doing????

Comment: Are you getting any error? please paste console log also.

Comment: In the generate page in browser look at the source of the page and tell us what is the form action set to ?

Comment: I think GWT might be adding something at the end of URL in which case your URL pattern does not match. Try changing that to `*/upload*` or `*/upload/*`

Comment: GWT.getModuleBaseURL() might not return the correct url, try using GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() instead. See this thread for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286204/gwt-getmodulebaseurl-returns-an-incorrect-value

Also, if that doesn't help, try looking in the browser debug console and see the request being sent.

Comment: There is no error on console , it just that in Window.alert(event.getResults()); it shows 404 error message for servlet.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, `*/upload` is not a valid servlet-mapping url-pattern. `*` can only be a prefix to "extensions" (as in `*.jsp`). You'd have to use `moduleName/upload`, or just `upload` and then change `getModuleBaseURL` for `getHostPageBaseURL`.

Comment: I modified code as you have suggested but i'm still getting the same problem of 404 for servlet.